# The advantage of c++11 threads

Tags: multithreading, c++11

> Threads are added to C++11 language

Then I am wondering what is the difference, advantages and impact?

If this code is by `c++03`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

void *call_from_thread(void *)
{
    std::cout << "Launched by thread" << std::endl;
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t t;

    pthread_create(&t, NULL, call_from_thread, NULL);

    pthread_join(t, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

and this one by `c++11`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void call_from_thread()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(call_from_thread);
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Then, I see no fundamental advantage.

Also, when it is said a part of language, I am confused about that as I see no new keyword or no new syntax. I just see a new standard library. Is it beyond that? and is this just a paraphrase of `pthread`?

Comment: The first one isn't portable to non-POSIX platforms. And `<thread>` is part of the C++ standard library (unlike `<pthread.h>`)

Comment: @UnholySheep, Did it have problem with windows?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. `pthread` doesn't exist on Windows, it is not a POSIX platform

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides being much more portable, C++11 threads also provides other benefits:

- allows passing arguments (and more than one) to the thread handler in a type safe way. `pthread_create` passes a single `void*`, whereas with `std::thread` you get compile time errors if something is wrong instead of runtime errors
- the thread handler can be a lambda
- a `std::thread` is an object, not a pointer, which makes managing object lifetimes easier, and reduces risk of dangling pointers, especially if combined with `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` if pointer juggling is even needed.

Those are the immediate benefits that come to mind.

As for standard library vs language spec: they are both part of the same standard, so they are both considered "C++11". Note that `std::thread` can *not* be implemented in C++03, since move semantics is new in C++11 and `std::thread` implements move.

Answer (score 4):

The primary advantage of C++ thread library is portability. Like many other C++ standard library facilities platform-dependent libraries like pthreads or Win32API provide more control over your threads comparing to C++ thread library. For instance on Windows Win32 API thread library allows you to set thread stack size you can't do with C++ thread library without using platform dependent code. API functions like `TerminateThread` allows developers to terminate their running threads (a very dangerous operation) or setting thread priority using function `SetThreadPriority`.

But, using C++ thread library makes your code platform independent. And it's not just about class `thread`. There are other facilities like mutexes, conditional variables, locks that have been standardized so every C++ implementation is supposed to implement them to comply with C++ standard.

So, using C++ thread library is always a trade-off. You are losing some degree of control over threads but your code is being portable. And if you really need some low level feature, you can use `std::thread::native_handle` that allows you to mix standard and platform dependent code.

This link [`std::thread::native_handle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle) provides a nice example how to mix class `thread` and pthread library.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds funny in 2019, but one small disadvantage of std::thread (since you asked about it) is ~130kb of code added to your binary.